# Order of execution of a nested for loop in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nested, order-of-execution

With a working solution found, I am trying to understand why my solution does not work. I have added the minimal working example (MWE), at first I show the working solution, then I show an attempted solution at 1. and at 2. I am printing all elements of the array manually, and then again in the for loop.

From that I conclude that the outer for loop (with counter `i`) is evaluated first and then after that the inner for loop (with counter `q`) is evaluated. I am confused and was wondering whether my understanding of the evaluation order of Java's for loops is incorrect, or whether I have a syntax/different error that I am missing.

**Question:** Could anyone suggest a reason for the order of evaluation of for loops?

```
public class LearnMultiDimensionalArrayLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Generate array
        double[][] a = {{1.5, -10.3, 0}, {-2.5, 8, 1.3}};
        // call method that loops through the array
        forloops(a);
    }

    public static void forloops(double[][] a) {
        // Working solution:
        //loops through all elements of the array and prints their values.
        for (double[] x : a)
        {
           for (double y : x)
           {
                System.out.print(y + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
        }

        // Now I tried my own solution:
        System.out.println("The first dimension length: "+ a.length + 
            " The second dim. length: " + a[1].length);
        System.out.println("first dim-1 ="+  (a.length -1));
        System.out.println("Second dim-1 ="+  (a[1].length -1));

        // Question to self: Why is the following for loop wrong?
        // for (int i=0;i <= a.length;i++){
        //   for (int q=0;q <= a[1].length;i++){
        //     System.out.println("["+i+"]"+"["+q+"]"+"="+a[i][q]);
        //   }
        // }

        // 1. Attempted Answer: Because the lengths are the nr of rows 
        // and nr of columns in the matrix. so with n = 2, there are only the elements
        // 0 and 1 in the first []
        // Test hypotheses by looping through the array a with length-1:

        // for (int i=0;i <= a.length-1;i++){
        //   for (int q=0;q <= a[1].length-1;i++){
        //     System.out.println("["+i+"]"+"["+q+"]"+"="+a[i][q]);
        //   }
        // }

        // Conclusion, that did solve the problem. 
        // 2. Attempt: Print all elements and their values, then compare
        // with what the for loop does:

        System.out.println("a[0][0]="+a[0][0]);
        System.out.println("a[0][1]="+a[0][1]);
        System.out.println("a[0][2]="+a[0][2]);
        System.out.println("a[1][0]="+a[1][0]);
        System.out.println("a[1][1]="+a[1][1]);
        System.out.println("a[1][2]="+a[1][2]);
        // System.out.println("a[2][0]="+a[2][0]);
        // System.out.println("a[2][1]="+a[2][1]);
        // System.out.println("a[2][2]="+a[2][2]);

        // 2.a Troubleshooting: verify the upper bound of the for loops
        // are not producing an error due to differences in types:
        System.out.println(((Object)1).getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(((Object)a[1].length).getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(((Object)(a[1].length-1)).getClass().getName());

       // All expressions are evaluated as integer, both i and q are integers
       // hence the different types should not result in a false negative.

        // The actual problematic for loop:
        System.out.println("Boolean evaluation:" + (1 == (a.length-1)));
        for (int i=0; (i <= (a.length-1));i++){
            for (int q=0; (q <= (a[1].length-1));i++){
                //System.out.println("retry" + "[i="+i+"]"+"[q="+q+"]"+"="+a[i][q]);
                System.out.println("This is the wrong order of for loops" + "[q="+q+"]"+"[i="+i+"]"+"="+a[q][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just write a simple program with nested loops, and a println statement in each loop, and you'll see how they are executed.

Comment: In your inner loop, you've got a copy-paste error: you're still incrementing `i`, but your loop counter is `q`.

Comment: Also, you seem to have flipped the columns and rows. In first solution (Foreach) For all Rows, you print all columns. But in the problematic loop, you have i (thats first, so thats row right?) then q (so column) but in print you take a[q][i] (where it should be a[row][column] to match foreach [and also to match the loop conditions and not get IndexOutOfBounds])

Comment: @azurefrog Thank you, that was indeed the problem, and the reason it appeared to be evaluating the for loops in reversed order.

Comment: @Worthless indeed thank you for your feedback, in my answer, I swapped them back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you run this piece of code and try to understand how it works... Once you do, play around (change the values) and see what happens

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    System.out.println("Inside the Fist loop "+i);
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
      System.out.println("Inside the second loop "+j);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I should have reverted back to an even more basic form of the for loop, without the additional code with the prints indicating position in the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick responses, as @azurefrog pointed out, I had a copy-paste error in the counter of q, therefore, it kept increasing i for the inner loop, yielding an out of bounds error on the row/column that the outer loop should be iterating through.

This contains the corrected code (with the out of bounds error in the second `for-loop` since the rows and columns have different lengths and are reversed as in the original question). I apologize.

```
public class SolvedMultiDimensionalArrayLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Generate array
        double[][] a = {{1.5, -10.3, 0}, {-2.5, 8, 1.3}};
        // call method that loops through the array
        forloops(a);
    }

    public static void forloops(double[][] a) {     
        // Reversed with the intended order:
        for (int i=0; (i <= (a.length-1));i++){
            for (int q=0; (q <= (a[1].length-1));q++){
                System.out.println("retry" + "[i="+i+"]"+"[q="+q+"]"+"="+a[i][q]);
                //System.out.println("This is the wrong order of for loops" + "[q="+q+"]"+"[i="+i+"]"+"="+a[q][i]);
            }
        }
        // The actual solution for loop:
        for (int i=0; (i <= (a.length-1));i++){
            for (int q=0; (q <= (a[1].length-1));q++){
                //System.out.println("retry" + "[i="+i+"]"+"[q="+q+"]"+"="+a[i][q]);
                System.out.println("This was the reversed order, with corrected counter" + "[q="+q+"]"+"[i="+i+"]"+"="+a[q][i]); 
                //error here, since a.length is shorter than a[1].length, and the columns and rows are reversed.

            }
        }

    }
}
```